# Basic php can't run in my browser. It includes the "$" , ";" and etc. in html

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP coding and I can't solve this problem[It's includes the variables and the endlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0C7V.png).

I'm new to the language.

Comment: how you run the file?

Comment: Please paste your code in your question, and try to be more specific

Comment: Is there actually PHP running on your computer?

Comment: There is PHP running on my computer. The code works yesterday and now it's back to the picture above.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other issue, fix your xampp problem, put your project in xampp > htdocs folder, save your file with .php extension and go to browser write http://localhost/project/page.php

Comment: pleasure is all mine

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** You are calling POST values, meaning a form (similar to a login form) has to send the values of `tireqty`, `oilqty`, and `sparkqty` to that page.

So you generally want to start a `.php` file with `<?php` at the very top. I would recommend doing a simple example like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<p>1</p>';
?>
<p>2</p>
```

Or, change your file to reflect `.html` instead. You *should* be able to still have the `php` run properly there like this:

```
<p>1</p>
<?php
    echo '<p>2</p>';
?>
```

If this doesn't work, please update your question to provide:

1. Operating System
2. What program you're using
3. What browser you're using
4. What version of PHP you're using
5. Any other information about your system

[php](/questions/tagged/php) [html](/questions/tagged/html) [server](/questions/tagged/server)

Comment: 1.WIndows 7 2. I'm using Notepad++ 3.Mozilla Firefox 4.PHP 7.0.2 5 5.When i star apache in xampp it gives me an error that says:  Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

Comment: Yesterday the code is working and after that , the picture above happened. I'm new to the language.

Comment: You should start your apache before you can run php.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the code because the code works yesterday . I think it's in the xampp and i need help on that. heres the error that my xampp gives:1:09:25 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:09:25 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:09:25 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

Comment: @raphael-biscocho - Not a problem. Did the edits to the question help though? I brought your code the question so it wouldn't get more down votes - people don't tend to like going through links to find stuff.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I'm really learning these stuffs right now.

Comment: Not a problem, so it looks like you're trying to make an inventory order page for vehicle parts. Is that the goal?

Comment: @raphael-biscocho, I would recommend accepting the suggested edits, it would allow other users to better understand your question